# Code to Select the first cell in a row after a loop finishes

Tags: vba, excel

I am working a loop macro that copies data until a cell is blank.

Once that cell is blank, I want to macro to select the cell in column A, in the same row that the loop criteria was satisfied.

This is what I have, the loop macro works fine but when I tried to code the macro to select the cell I get an error.

```
Range("C8:V8").Select
Selection.Copy
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 15) = ""

ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Range("A1").Select
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to copy/paste, but this line will select the cell in column A, for the last row in your spreadsheet:

```
Range(Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)).Select
```

If this doesn't achieve what you are looking for, showing the data you are copying/looping through would be helpful.

It seems that your loop should never end in your code, however, since your end condition ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 15) always looks where you just finished copying the contents from Cells "C8:V8".

At the end, you will get an error selecting ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Range("A1") because it is trying to select 6 columns to the left of your original selection, which began at column 3 (aka C).

It seems that your problem might stem from a misunderstanding of how the ActiveCell.Offset().Range("") syntax works.  I recommend the answer in this post if that's the case -> [i need interpretation of activecell.offset in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535646/i-need-interpretation-of-activecell-offset-in-vba)

Comment: Hi, the loop copies a row of formulas down until the forumula in a specific cell comes back as blank and the the loop stops.  I will attach an image of the spread sheet to my post.

After the loop stops I would like the macro to select the cell in column A that is one row below the row where the loop stopped.

Comment: I tried to add an image but the website will not let me.

Comment: OK, I understand why your loop ends then if you are copying formulas.  When you said "data" I interpreted that as values, which would cause your loop to never end.  If the formula in the 15th row calculates to "", then it makes sense your loop would end.  You still are trying to select off of the page, however, when you try to select 6 columns to the left of column C.  `ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select` will select column A, as it's 2 to the left of column C.